# Issues with figures when rendering rmarkdown/bookdown to pdf

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, figure

In the last 3 days something has happened to RMarkdown. When rendering the default .rmd file produced by RStudio to a PDF file, the plot created has no margins beyond the plot axes and the axis scales and titles are not visible. When rendering to .html or Word format, the figures are as they should be. Today I reinstalled R and RStudio and updated all of the libraries (update.packages()) and the problem remains. This first cropped up in a bookdown project so I checked the .png files that bookdown produces and they all have the same problem - no axis scales or titles and the axis margins are at the figure limits.

Update: I un/reinstalled miktex and the pdf compiled correctly. When I removed MikTex and used tinytex instead, the axes were cutoff again. If I use MikTex instead of tinytex, every rmarkdown chunk generates an error that the MikTex database is locked by another program (no other apps were running so it much be something in the background) and results in a ~1-2 minute delay and a total compile times approach 45 minutes (before this problem it was ~5 minutes, still pretty slow). So it appears that there's an issue with tinytex and how it generates the .png files. I'm at a loss.
Any thoughts?

Current versions

```
R $version.string
[1] "R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)"
RStudio version
[1] ‘2022.2.1.461’
```

Answer (score 1):

for me...
worked again after returning to earlier tinytex version
tinytex::install_tinytex(version = "2021.03")
tinytex::tlmgr("option repository [https://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tug/historic/systems/texlive/2020/tlnet-final"](https://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tug/historic/systems/texlive/2020/tlnet-final%22))

for me, the PDF image files in figure_latex folder lacked axis/titles

happened shortly after I re-installed tinytex, even for the simplest code:

rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd",output_format='pdf_document')

in the jaml
output:
pdf_document:
keep_tex: true

```
plot(1:10,xlab='as 1',ylab='as 2')
```

html worked fine